# Is it possible to know when an associated object is about to be destroyed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When you have a one-to-many association in Rails 3 and accept nested attributes with delete, is it possible to know by looking at the objects (the associated object) whether it's going to be deleted or not?

For example:

```
group.attributes = {:member_attributes => {"0" => {:id => 1, :name => "John"},
                                           "1" => {:id => 2, :name => "Dave"},
                                           "2" => {:id => 3, :name => "Gus", "_destroy" => true}}}
```

Is it possible by looking at group.members to know that the one with id 3 is going to be deleted on save?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a method for finding that out, called marked_for_destruction?

```
group.members.each do |member|
    puts "#{member.name} => #{member.marked_for_destruction?}"
end
```

would generate

```
John false
Dave false
Gus true
```